# prove the following using the triangle inequality

Tags: inequality, absolute-value, triangle-inequality

QUESTION: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB1Cq.jpg

can anyone check my MY ANS:

let a , b, c ∈ R. then

| |a| + b - c| = ||a|| + (b - c)|

| |a| + b - c| ≤ ||a|| + |b - c| ---- by triangle inequality and x=|a| and y= b - c

≤ ||a|| + |b| + |-c| ---- triangle again on |b - c| [and -c = +(-c)]

≤ |a| + |b| + |c| ---- |-c| = |c| and ||a||=|a|

Comment: You should use MathJax and include the question in the text rather than link an image.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer looks OK

By the triangle inequality:
$$|a|+|b|+|c|=||a||+|b|+|-c|\geq||a||+|b-c|\geq||a|+b-c|.$$

Comment: Your answer looks OK.

Comment: so ibased on that my answer looks right?

Comment: @Kero Tero  Yes, your solution is right.